# Нужен совет по структуре проекта и именованию БЭМ

Tags: инспекция-кода, sass, структуры, pug, бэм

В своей практике я использую `БЭМ` + `pug` и `sass`.

`БЭМ` позволяет удобно разбивать элементы на блоки. Каждый блок - директория, которая содержит `pug` и `sass` файлы. Это позволяет с одной стороны использовать блоки в разных проектах, я просто скопирую нужную мне директорию, вставлю в проект и все работает.

Выглядит это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же это очень удобно тем, что когда я инспектирую верстку, могу очень быстро по названию класса понять, где искать нужный код стилей.

Допустим, я хочу подкорректировать стили в `block-text__title`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я мгновенно нахожу нужный мне код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, довольно часто встречается ситуация, когда буквально 2-3 элемента образуют блок, при этом этот блок не имеет смысла вне родителя.

Например, как здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`request` всегда будет находиться внутри `pop-up` и в то же время дочерние элементы `request`, я не буду называть `pop-up__icon` и `pop-up__content`, потому что у меня могут возникнуть именно `__icon` и `__content` относящиеся непосредственно к `pop-up`.

В то же время придумывать какие-то другие именования данным блокам, кроме как `__icon` и `__content` тоже не стоит, может возникнуть путаница. Просто я знаю, что все иконки имеют `__icon` и все.

Выносить `request` отдельным блоком можно, но имеет ли это смысл? 2 элемента, ради них создавать отдельный переиспользуемый блок, при том, что я точно знаю, что этот блок будет только в рамках `pop-up`. Тоже на мой взгляд не имеет смысла.

Так же можно стили `request` просто написать в том же файле, что и стили `pop-up`

```
.pop-up
   &__content
      display: block
      // Какие-то стили
.request
   &__content
      display: table
      // Какие-то стили
```

Но это вносит путаницу, когда я хочу исправить стили `request`, и не нахожу такого отдельного файла, мне приходится смотреть, внутри какого блока находится `request`, смотреть структуру родителя, убедившись, что данный родитель - это нужный блок, искать внутри его стилей. Одним словом путаница и пустая трата времени.

Можно использовать другой подход.

Не создавать отдельный переиспользуемый блок, в котором будут и `pug` файл и `sass` файл. А создать блок в котором будет только `sass` файл. Так я быстро найду нужные мне стили.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у данного метода есть недостаток:

Допустим, я хочу использовать `pop-up` из прошлого проекта в новом проекте. Естественно я не держу в голове, что `request` отдельно. Я скопирую директорию содержащую файлы `pop-up` и обнаружу, что стили `request` не подключились. И хорошо, если отдельно лежит только один блок (`request`), а если их 50? Предстоит нудная работа по просмотру стилей блока и поиска нужных блоков, которые не подключились.

Посоветуйте, каким образом лучше структурировать работу и как при этом использовать `БЭМ`? Спасибо!